# Android number notification

Tags: android, notifications

How do apps like accuweather and the weather channel get their small/ticket notification icons to be the temperature (with the degree symbol and something colored for emergency weather)? The icon is resource I'd and something that doesn't seem able to be dynamic. Is the only way to make resources for each number?

Comment: Isn't it just a textview with a custom font and an image background with transparent edges, with layout_gravity set to centered_horizontal?

Answer (score 0):

Correct—you cannot create resources dynamically, or assign a non-resource drawable as a notification icon. My guess is that those apps just have a resource for each number.